# Design Pattern for different users

Tags: java, object, oop, design-patterns

I have 2 different types of users in my app: `LoggedInUser` and `GuestUser`
They both have same functionalities such as `createNewOrder` and `cancelOrder` (the implementation should be different) but `LoggedInUser` can do much more such as `WriteReview`,`FavouriteProduct` etc.

I want a design pattern for these types of users, so that I don't check which type of user my application has at the moment and I just call the method without knowing the actual type of the user.

Is it even possible to do this? Which design pattern is the most suitable?

What I have done so far is creating an abstract class called `User` which has the similar functionalities:

```java
abstract class User{
    void createOrder()
    void cancelOrder()
}
```

and also a class for `LoggedInUser` and a class for `GuestUser`:

```java
class LoggedInUser extends User {
    //some instance variables

    void favouriteProduct(String id) {
      //...
    }

    void writeReview(Review review) {
        //...
    }
  
    @override
    void cancelOrder(){
         //...
    }
  
    @override
    void cancelOrder(){
         //...
    }
}

class GuestUser extends User {
    //some instance variables
 
    @override
    void cancelOrder(){
       //...
    }

    @override
    void cancelOrder(){
       //...
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: When clicking on the "Add to favourites" you know which endpoint to call. That endpoint will work with LoggedInUser from the beginning, not with the interface. So there shouldn't be a problem..

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev The thing is I don't want to check the user type at the run time. The default user class doesn't have `favouriteProdocut` method so when I call it, it won't work unless I check the type of the object. am I right?

Comment: But in the code which invokes anything related with the `favouriteProduct` - you will only work with `LoggedInUser`s, there won't be any `GuestUser`s, right? If not - could you also add the piece of code that you have in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure but **Strategy Pattern** looks good here. https://www.baeldung.com/java-strategy-pattern

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev yes but when I log in the user, I have a variable of type `User` and then I assign it either a `GuestUser` or a `LoggedInUser` based on the action taken on login screen.

Comment: You don't want two classes. You want one `User` class such that each user has a set of roles, and each method checks whether this user has the corresponding role. Roles would include `writeReview`, `favouriteProduct`, etc. They are basically just strings, they have no actions themselves. You probably also want to add some administrative roles.

Comment: @user207421 that’s a really good solution but what if one of the roles need extra instance variables? (LoggedInUser for example has email and username which is not necessary for GuestUser to have one) how can I have extra fields for one role in my class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are absolutely dead set against have to check which type of user you have, and want to treat them the same way no matter what (I'm not sure why you would want that), you can add default implementations of the `favouriteProduct` and `writeReview` methods in your abstract `User` class. These default implementations would be used when calling them on `GuestUser` instances, while you would override them in your `LoggedInUser`. I think this is *not* a great design.

```
public class UserExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        User loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser();
        User guestUser = new GuestUser();

        loggedInUser.favouriteProduct("123");
        guestUser.favouriteProduct("123");

        Review review = new Review();
        review.text = "This product is amazing.";

        loggedInUser.writeReview(review);
        guestUser.writeReview(review);
    }
}

abstract class User
{
    abstract void createOrder();

    abstract void cancelOrder();

    public void favouriteProduct(String id)
    {
        System.out.printf("UserAbstract::favouriteProduct(%s)%n", id);
    }

    public void writeReview(Review review)
    {
        System.out.printf("UserAbstract::writeReview%n\t%s%n", review.text);
    }
}

class LoggedInUser extends User
{
    //some instance variables

    @Override
    public void favouriteProduct(String id)
    {
        System.out.printf("LoggedInUser::favouriteProduct(%s)%n", id);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeReview(Review review)
    {
        System.out.printf("LoggedInUser::writeReview%n\t%s%n", review.text);
    }

    @Override
    public void createOrder()
    {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelOrder()
    {
        //...
    }
}

class GuestUser extends User
{
    //some instance variables

    @Override
    public void createOrder()
    {
        //...
    }

    @Override
    public void cancelOrder()
    {
        //...
    }
}


class Review
{
    public String text;
}
```

You would probably be better off moving the `favouriteProduct` and `writeReview` methods to a service class. Those methods could accept instances that implement the `User` interface, then decide how to handle instances of `LoggedInUsers` vs `GuestUsers` differently. This allows you to pass users around pretty generically and only branch when absolutely necessary. You can ignore `GuestUsers` in the service methods, throw an exception, redirect to a login, whatever you want. IMO that kind of logic doesn't belong in your business objects.

```
public class UserExample2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        LoggedInUser loggedInUser = new LoggedInUser();
        GuestUser guestUser = new GuestUser();

        UserService.favouriteProduct(loggedInUser, "123");
        UserService.favouriteProduct(guestUser, "123");

        Review review = new Review();
        review.text = "This product is amazing.";

        UserService.writeReview(loggedInUser, review);
        UserService.writeReview(guestUser, review);
    }
}

interface User
{
    void createOrder();

    void cancelOrder();
}

class LoggedInUser implements User
{
    //some instance variables

    public void createOrder()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void cancelOrder()
    {
        //...
    }
}

class GuestUser implements User
{
    //some instance variables

    public void createOrder()
    {
        //...
    }

    public void cancelOrder()
    {
        //...
    }
}

class UserService
{
    public static void favouriteProduct(LoggedInUser user, String id)
    {
        System.out.printf("UserService::favouriteProduct LoggedInUser favourites %s%n", id);
    }

    public static void favouriteProduct(GuestUser user, String id)
    {
        System.out.printf("UserService::favouriteProduct GuestUser favourites %s%n", id);
    }

    public static void writeReview(LoggedInUser user, Review review)
    {
        System.out.printf("UserService::writeReview LoggedInUser writes%n\t%s%n", review.text);
    }

    public static void writeReview(GuestUser user, Review review)
    {
        System.out.printf("UserService::writeReview GuestUser writes%n\t%s%n", review.text);
    }
}

class Review
{
    public String text;
}
```

[Edit]

Here is a more thorough example of how to solve this kind or problem. This more clearly illustrates how polymorphism and inheritance can be used to implement common functionality across different types of sessions in a typical e-commerce cart scenario.

```
import java.util.*;

public class UserExample3
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Set up our user with test data IRL this would be retrieved from authentication mechanism
        Address userAddress = new Address("1313 Mockingbird Lane", "London", "GB", "12345");
        User loggedInUser = new User(23, "Alice", userAddress);

        // Set up a session for our user
        UserSession userSession = new UserSession(loggedInUser);

        // Set up a guest session
        GuestSession guestSession = new GuestSession();

        // Add items - action happens in the abstract class
        userSession.addOrderItem("123", 2);
        guestSession.addOrderItem("456", 3);

        // Favourite items - action happens in the concrete classes
        userSession.favouriteProduct("123");
        guestSession.favouriteProduct("456");

        // List items via the cart service, requires instances of Session interface
        CartService.listCartItems(userSession);
        CartService.listCartItems(guestSession);

        // Write reviews via the Review service, requires instances of Session interface
        Review userReview = ReviewService.writeReview(userSession, "123", "This product is amazing");
        System.out.println(userReview);

        Review guestReview = ReviewService.writeReview(guestSession, "456", "This product is pants");
        System.out.println(guestReview);

        // Create orders via the order service, requires instances of Session interface
        Order userOrder = null;
        try
        {
            userOrder = OrderService.createOrderFromSession(userSession);
            System.out.println(userOrder);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Guest checkout requires us to collect an address (user already has address saved in their profile)
        Address guestAddress = new Address("1060 W. Addison", "Chicago", "US", "12345");
        guestSession.setAddress(guestAddress);

        Order guestOrder = null;
        try
        {
            guestOrder = OrderService.createOrderFromSession(guestSession);
            System.out.println(guestOrder);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        // Estimate shipping charges via cart service
        double userEstimate = CartService.estimateShipping(userSession);
        System.out.printf("User shipping estimate: %.2f%n", userEstimate);

        double guestEstimate = CartService.estimateShipping(guestSession);
        System.out.printf("Guest shipping estimate: %.2f%n", guestEstimate);

        // Convert a guest session to a user session via CartService - requires concrete classes
        UserSession newUserSession = new UserSession(loggedInUser);
        CartService.populateUserSessionCartFromGuestSession(newUserSession, guestSession);

            /*
                The guest session items are now in the user session
                and the guest session favorites have been added to the user

                Requires instances of Session interface
             */
        CartService.listCartItems(newUserSession);
        System.out.println(loggedInUser);

        // Empty the cart via the cart service
        CartService.emptyCart(newUserSession);
        CartService.listCartItems(newUserSession);

        // Cancel an order via the order service - will be null if validation failed
        if(userOrder != null)
        {
            OrderService.cancelOrder(userOrder);
            System.out.println(userOrder);
        }

        // Complete an order via the order service - will be null if validation failed
        if(guestOrder != null)
        {
            OrderService.completeOrder(guestOrder);
            System.out.println(guestOrder);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Do cart things
 */
class CartService
{
    /**
     * Print the line items in a cart
     * <p>
     * This is an example of polymorphism - any instance that implements the
     * Session interface will work here
     *
     * @param session instance of interface Session
     */
    public static void listCartItems(Session session)
    {
        System.out.println("Order items:");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> currItem : session.getOrderItems().entrySet())
        {
            System.out.printf("\t%s: %d%n", currItem.getKey(), currItem.getValue());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Populate a UserSession with data collected in a guest session
     * Used when a user begins their order while unauthenticated, the logs in prior to completing the order
     *
     * @param userSession  Instance of UserSession
     * @param guestSession Instance of GuestSession
     */
    public static void populateUserSessionCartFromGuestSession(UserSession userSession, GuestSession guestSession)
    {
        userSession.getOrderItems().putAll(guestSession.getOrderItems());

        userSession.getUser().getFavouriteProducts().addAll(guestSession.getFavouriteProducts());

        guestSession.clearOrderItems();
    }

    /**
     * Clear the items from a cart
     * <p>
     * This is an example of polymorphism - any instance that implements the
     * Session interface will work here
     *
     * @param session Instance of Session interface
     */
    public static void emptyCart(Session session)
    {
        session.clearOrderItems();
    }

    public static double estimateShipping(Session session)
    {
        Map<String, Double> perItemChargesByCountry = new HashMap<>();
        perItemChargesByCountry.put("US", 1.23);
        perItemChargesByCountry.put("GB", 1.05);

        String countryCode = session.getAddress().getCountry();
        Double perItemCharge = perItemChargesByCountry.get(countryCode);

        int numItems = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> currLineItem : session.getOrderItems().entrySet())
        {
            numItems += currLineItem.getValue();
        }

        return numItems * perItemCharge;
    }
}

/**
 * Do order things
 */
class OrderService
{
    /**
     * Create an order from the line items in a cart
     * <p>
     * This is an example of polymorphism - any instance that implements the
     * Session interface will work here
     * <p>
     * If the session is an instance of UserSession, data available only on
     * those instances will be set on the order record
     *
     * @param session Instance of Session interface
     * @return Order
     */
    public static Order createOrderFromSession(Session session) throws Exception
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setStatus(Order.Status.PENDING);
        order.setAddress(session.getAddress());
        order.getItems().putAll(session.getOrderItems());

        if (session instanceof UserSession)
        {
            order.setUser(((UserSession) session).getUser());
        }

        if(!order.validate())
        {
            throw new Exception("Something is wrong with the order");
        }

        return order;
    }

    /**
     * Cancel an order by changing its status
     *
     * @param order Order
     */
    public static void cancelOrder(Order order)
    {
        order.setStatus(Order.Status.CANCELLED);
    }

    /**
     * Complete an order by changing its status
     *
     * @param order Order
     */
    public static void completeOrder(Order order)
    {
        order.setStatus(Order.Status.COMPLETE);
    }
}

/**
 * Do review things
 */
class ReviewService
{
    /**
     * Create a product review
     * <p>
     * This is an example of polymorphism - any instance that implements the
     * Session interface will work here
     * <p>
     * If the session is an instance of UserSession, data available only on
     * those instances will be set on the review record
     *
     * @param session   Session
     * @param productId String
     * @param text String content of review
     * @return Review
     */
    public static Review writeReview(Session session, String productId, String text)
    {
        Review review = new Review();

        if (session instanceof UserSession)
        {
            review.setUser(((UserSession) session).getUser());
        }

        review.setProductId(productId);
        review.setText(text);

        return review;
    }
}

/**
 * Describe the contract that all session classes should adhere to
 */
interface Session
{
    Address getAddress();

    Map<String, Integer> getOrderItems();

    void setOrderItems(Map<String, Integer> orderItems);

    void addOrderItem(String productId, int quantity);

    void removeOrderItem(String productId);

    void clearOrderItems();

    void favouriteProduct(String productId);
}

/**
 * Implement functionality common to all concrete session classes
 */
abstract class SessionAbstract
{
    private Map<String, Integer> orderItems = new HashMap<>();

    public Map<String, Integer> getOrderItems()
    {
        return orderItems;
    }

    public void setOrderItems(Map<String, Integer> orderItems)
    {
        this.orderItems = orderItems;
    }

    public void addOrderItem(String productId, int quantity)
    {
        if (orderItems.containsKey(productId))
        {
            quantity += orderItems.get(productId);
        }

        orderItems.put(productId, quantity);
    }

    public void removeOrderItem(String productId)
    {
        orderItems.remove(productId);
    }

    public void clearOrderItems()
    {
        orderItems.clear();
    }
}

/**
 * Concrete session class for authenticated users
 */
class UserSession extends SessionAbstract implements Session
{
    private final User user;

    public UserSession(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    public Address getAddress()
    {
        return user.getAddress();
    }

    public void favouriteProduct(String productId)
    {
        user.addFavouriteProduct(productId);
    }
}

/**
 * Concrete session class for guest users
 *
 * We need to have an instance of Address and collection of favourite items
 * here since we don't have a user instance
 */
class GuestSession extends SessionAbstract implements Session
{
    private Address address;
    Set<String> favouriteProducts = new TreeSet<>();

    public Address getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Set<String> getFavouriteProducts()
    {
        return favouriteProducts;
    }

    public void favouriteProduct(String productId)
    {
        favouriteProducts.add(productId);
    }
}

class Address
{
    String street;
    String city;
    String country;
    String postCode;

    public Address(String street, String city, String country, String postCode)
    {
        this.street = street;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }

    public String getStreet()
    {
        return street;
    }

    public void setStreet(String street)
    {
        this.street = street;
    }

    public String getCity()
    {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city)
    {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getCountry()
    {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPostCode()
    {
        return postCode;
    }

    public void setPostCode(String postCode)
    {
        this.postCode = postCode;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Address{" + "street='" + street + '\'' + ", city='" + city + '\'' + ", country='" + country + '\'' + ", postCode='" + postCode + '\'' + '}';
    }
}

class User
{
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Address address;
    Set<String> favouriteProducts = new TreeSet<>();

    public User(Integer id, String name, Address address)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Integer getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Address getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Set<String> getFavouriteProducts()
    {
        return favouriteProducts;
    }

    public void setFavouriteProducts(Set<String> favouriteProducts)
    {
        this.favouriteProducts = favouriteProducts;
    }

    public void addFavouriteProduct(String productId)
    {
        favouriteProducts.add(productId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", address=" + address + ", favouriteProducts=" + favouriteProducts + '}';
    }
}

class Order
{
    public enum Status
    {
        PENDING, CANCELLED, COMPLETE
    }

    private Status status;
    private User user;
    private Address address;
    private Map<String, Integer> items = new HashMap<>();

    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public Address getAddress()
    {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address)
    {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public Map<String, Integer> getItems()
    {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(Map<String, Integer> items)
    {
        this.items = items;
    }

    public Status getStatus()
    {
        return status;
    }

    public void setStatus(Status status)
    {
        this.status = status;
    }

    public boolean validate()
    {
        boolean valid = true;

        if(items.isEmpty())
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        else if(address == null)
        {
            valid = false;
        }
        else if(status == null)
        {
            valid = false;
        }

        return valid;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Order{" + "status=" + status + ", user=" + user + ", address=" + address + ", items=" + items + '}';
    }
}

class Review
{
    private String productId;
    private String text;
    private User user;

    public String getProductId()
    {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId)
    {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getText()
    {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        String name = (user != null) ? user.getName() : "Anonymous Coward";

        return "Review{" + "productId='" + productId + '\'' + ", text='" + text + '\'' + ", user=" + name + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: What I needed was to not check for the type of user in the code and have a single `User` instance which acts differently based on its type. I don't think what I want is possible because both users have some difference. If I go with your second solution, I still have to check the type of user before calling a method. I'm not saying it's bad to do that whenever I want to do something but I suppose there has to be a way of doing it without checking the exact type. but the second solution looks really good to me. Thanks

Comment: You actually don't have to manually check the type of user with either of these. I mean, you have to treat them differently at some point because they *are* different, but that's not a bad thing. The second example is the "more correct" OOP approach, you're leveraging polymorphism to figure out how to treat different instances rather than building manual logic. I build a *lot* of systems like this, and #2 is a type of pattern I use often.

Comment: What I'm thinking is that I have to have 2 variables, one is LoggedInUser and one is GuestUser. if user logs in, GuestUser will be null. if user continues as Guest, then LoggedInUser will be null. Then I have to check which one is null and which one isn't before calling any method of UserServices. Am I right? that's why I think it's a problem. I might be completely wrong :)

Comment: Oh, no, I wouldn't do that. If you're going the route of having different concrete classes that implement a common interface or extend a common abstract class, you have one User instance that can be either GuestUser or LoggedInUser, then treat them differently as needed.

On the other hand, you could go a completely different route and have a session management object, with a flag for whether or not the user is logged in, and if so, you can get an instance of LoggedInUser, and if not, just don't do "user things". That limits what you can do with non-logged-in users, but it is simple.

Comment: If I use your approach and pass the user instance (it's either LoggedInUser or GuestUser but the type of the variable is User), then will the appropriate method of `UserService` be called based on the User instance?

Comment: Yes, that's the magic of polymorphism :) You can copy the example into a file called UserExample2.java, then run javac UserExample2.java && java UserExample2 from the command line to compile and run it and poke around.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the talk of OOP and polymorphism, which I understand to be referring to the second piece of code. A service full of `static` methods is not object oriented. It's procedural. There is no polymorphism in this service, because it is programming to concrete implementations, not programming to an interface. Am I missing something here?

Comment: In this case, polymorphism means that an instance of an interface can be used as if it were of different types. The caller passes an instance that implements the User class to the service, which determines the appropriate method to actually call based on the concrete class. Not sure what you mean when you say a service full of static methods "is not object oriented, it's procedural".

Comment: I'm talking about the `UserService` class with four `static` methods. Is that what you're referring to as polymorphism, or is it something else?

Comment: Ha, you're right - I initially wrote it with two methods that accepted a User and did an instanceof check inside, then changed it due to the OP's aversion to type checking. Dock one point from my hacker card.

Comment: so isn't it polymorphism then?

Comment: I've updated the example to show polymorphism - all methods accept instances of User - the createOrder and cancelOrder are good examples because they don't care when the concrete class is, they only operate on the contract described in the interface.

Comment: @RobRuchte can this be implemented with spring security?